# Android App not showing Launcher Icon when downloaded from Play Store - padding also shows up

Tags: android, google-play

i have researched my problem but there are very conflicting answers regarding the issue.

My App has been approved by Google and is live.

However it is different.

When i use the .apk from my PC on my Phone everything works as intended.

Should i use:

```
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

or

```
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
```

in my androidmanifest.xml?

I also use

```
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">0dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">0dp</dimen>
```

in the dimens.xml

but the blue borders and app title do still show when i download it from the Play Store.

Thanks for all the help i can get!

Comment: Dosn't actually matter if you use mipmap or drawable, it's just a folder - but Google's Android Studio default is mipmap!
(You need to keep the image on the right folder, thought).

Comment: What blue borders are you referring to?

Comment: all the icons are in the right folders inside of android studio

by blue borders i mean stuff like this:

http://androidcoding.space/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/hello-world08-e1460218327660.png

i specifically got rid of it by using the 0dp dimen

Comment: Okay, the darker color is defined by the **colorPrimaryDark**. (configurable at **style.xml**).
The other color, is the toolbar, also configurable in your style!

If you want to remove it, you need to change your theme style to:  `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"`
 or
`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"`

Comment: I did that. Forgot to mention i guess. I use

     `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">`

in my manifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

Its really weird that you are having different result when downloading from Google Play. Check that you uploaded the same version as the one you are using locally.

And in android:icon you should use @mipmap

Comment: i only made one so i am pretty sure i uploaded the correct one to the play store